# What does this firebase CLI message mean

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-functions, firebase-tools

I have upgraded firebase-tools from v11 to v12.5.2

After this upgrade I get this when I use firebase deploy --only functions

```
 functions: Finished running predeploy script.
i  functions: preparing codebase default for deployment
i  functions: ensuring required API cloudfunctions.googleapis.com is enabled...
i  functions: ensuring required API cloudbuild.googleapis.com is enabled...
i  artifactregistry: ensuring required API artifactregistry.googleapis.com is enabled...
✔  artifactregistry: required API artifactregistry.googleapis.com is enabled
✔  functions: required API cloudbuild.googleapis.com is enabled
✔  functions: required API cloudfunctions.googleapis.com is enabled
i  functions: Loading and analyzing source code for codebase default to determine what to deploy
Serving at port 8958

{"severity":"INFO","message":"shutdown requested via /__/quitquitquit"}


Error: User code failed to load. Cannot determine backend specification
```

What is it that it serves at port 8xxx (the number varies)?
Does anybody know what is causing this?

When I try a second time I still get

```
Serving at port 8958
    
    {"severity":"INFO","message":"shutdown requested via /__/quitquitquit"}
```

But not the error so the functions are deployed.

I have tried to run firebase init functions and I have deleted node-modules and package-lock.json and run npm install, but none of it has helped.

I am using nodejs verison 18.

This basic Angular project with firebase project https://github.com/gongevangen/test shows the problem if you run "firebase deploy --only functions" in the functions folder.

Comment: Please edit the question to show the configuration and code that reproduces the behavior.  Ideally we should have a minimal complete reproducible example specified in your post so that we can see it for ourselves.

Comment: Lately, I've been getting the `quitquitquit` error every time I deploy cloud functions as well. However, I'm never unable to deploy them. Everything seems to work fine on my end despite this error message.